# Редактирование данных в mysql таблице через php

Tags: php, mysql

ДОброго вечера! Возникла проблемка в следующем деле, есть необходимость сделать для одного сайта некое подобие админ панели для управления юзерами - вывести их список и интересующие поля. Все данные юзеров хранятся в БД  mysql. 
С выводом списка, я справился, а вот с редактированием где-то у меня косяк вылез :(
Помогите пожалуйста:

```
 <?php


if (isset($_GET['del_id'])) { //проверяем, есть ли переменная на удаление
    $sql = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `hyldia_users` WHERE `id` = '.$_GET['del_id']); //удаляем строку из таблицы
}

if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) { //Проверяем, передана ли переменная на редактирования
    if (isset($_POST['nick'])) { //Если новое имя предано, то обновляем и имя и цену
        $sql = mysql_query('UPDATE `hyldia_users` SET '
                .'`nick` = "'.$_POST['nick'].'",'
                .'`money` = '.$_POST['money'].' '
                .'WHERE `id` = '.$_GET['red_id']);
    }
}
?>

<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hyldia_users`", $link);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo     '<tr><td>'.$result['id'].'</td>'.
         '<td>'.$result['nick'].'</td>'.
         '<td>'.$result['money'].' рублей</td>'.
         '<td><a href="?del_id='.$result['id'].'">Удалить</a></td>'.
         '<td><a href="?red_id='.$result['id'].'">Редактировать</a>.        </td></tr>';
     }
     ?>
  </table>
 <?php
  if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) { //Если передана переменная на    редактирование
    //Достаем запсись из БД
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hyldia_users` WHERE `id`=".$_GET['red_id'], $link); //запрос к БД
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql); //получение самой записи


    ?>
  <table>
  <form action="" method="post">
   <tr>
    <td>Игрок:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="nick" value="<?php echo ($result['nick']); ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Баланс:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="money" size="3" value="<?php echo ($result['money']); ?>"> руб.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
    <?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: опишите проблемы. опишите, что вам не понятно.

Comment: таблица вывелась, но вот кнопки редактирования не работают, происходит редирект на главную.

Comment: попробуйте сделать [mcve]

Comment: сократил код, я здесь первый раз поэтому если что-то не так делаю, прошу прощения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый и самый очевидный косяк, хоть и не относящийся на прямую к ответу - почему в 2017м вы используете модуль MYSQL а не [MYSQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo).

**Пример соединения с использованием mysqli:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Второй явный косяк - вставка переменных в запросы напрямую. Необходимо обработать переменные перед формированием запроса:

```
if($_GET['del_id']){
    $id = intval($_GET['del_id']);// ожидаем integer
}
```

Смысл в том, что бы проверить каждую входящую переменную на соответствие ожидаемому типу данных и отсутствие "примесей". Далее можно формировать запрос:

```
if (!$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `hyldia_users` WHERE `id` = '.$id"){
    echo " . $mysqli->erro . " " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

**Выборка данных и формирование таблицы(mysqli):**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `hyldia_users`";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
echo "<table>";//в своём примере вы не открыли таблицу
/* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>$row['id']";
        ... ... ...
        echo "</td></tr>"
    }
echo "</table>";
/* удаление выборки */
$result->free();
}
```

**Запрос на изменение данных по выбранной записи(mysqli):**

передавать name как параметр не корректно, правильнее все-таки id(уникальное значение). Поэтому лучше формируйте так:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo ($result['id']); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="nick" value="<?php echo ($result['nick']); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="money" size="3" value="<?php echo ($result['money']); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

if($_POST){   
  $id = intval($_POST['id']);
  ...
  $money = intval($_POSt['money'])// intval только если money не может быть минусовым, иначе (int)
  $query = "UPDATE hyldia_users SET money = $money, nick = $nick ... WHERE id= $id";
  $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

Если вы не разделяете логику и представление, т.е. у вас всё происходит в одном файле, то проверку $_post и операции изменения (удаление,изменение,добавление) производите в первую очередь, в самом начале файла что бы последующая выборка данных в таблицу отображала актуальные данные.

Все примеры построены на примерах использования модуля [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php), советую обучаться по нему а так же пробовать [расширения](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.database.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
"DELETE FROM `hyldia_users` WHERE `id` = '.$_GET['del_id']
```

Такой код - самый верный путь к [SQL-инъекциям](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Представьте, что получится, если в значении параметра del_id будет передано '0 OR TRUE'.

Используйте вызов запроса с параметрами. См., например, http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: вас тут еще вдобавок `GET`-запрос для удаления не смущает, как и использование устаревшего расширения `mysql_*`? зы: по факту это не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Не ответ - да, знаю. К сожалению, у меня пока недостаточно прав комментировать чужие ответы. И пройти мимо такого примера тоже не смог, поэтому пришлось писать как ответ.

Comment: За совет благодарю, перепишу обязательно эту часть, пока к сожалению не профессионал далеко в php и писал на основании найденного урока.
Но пока мне все-таки хочется увидеть, каким образом можно решить проблему с редактированием.

Answer (score 0):

Развернул ваш код и у меня он работает как требуется)
Можно попробовать сделать следующим образом - данные для редактирования полностью передать в данных формы, по-моему это будет логично - добавить скрытое поле в форму`<input type="hidden" name="red_id" value="<?php echo ($result['id']); ?>`
В строке `if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) { //Проверяем, передана ли переменная на редактирования` - заменить GET на POST. Вообще очень рекомендую посмотреть в сторону PDO.